# Disable the Underline Keyboard and shortcut Option in windows 7 from Registry

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I user Tweak me and ultimate windows tweaker and I have somehow managed to turn on the Underline Keyboard and shortcut Option now I find it impossible to turn it off.

I Ease of Access the "Underline Keyboard and shortcut Option" is unchecked but still I get the underline under the menu everywere.......

So I am wondering somewhere in the registry I can turn it off...

I went through this article but didnt help..

http://www.windowsvalley.com/get-underlined-keyboard-shortcuts-and-access-keys-permanently/

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you use a different user account?

Comment: No that works perfectly...I am concerned because this is my primary account

Comment: Open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7), run the following command, and then post here the full output: `reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v "UserPreferencesMask" & reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Preference" /v "On"`